# Moodle 4.2.3 Is it possibe to create a local plugin to recalculate grade (course final grade)?

Tags: moodle

I know how to create a local plugin exactly for my moodle version: 4.2.3.

- I would like to know if it's possible to create a local plugin to recalculate course final grade (please specify how can i do it).
- Also, I want to know if special event function exists to apply a course grade final note method or algorithm I can use in lib.php (please explain a little).
- List item

else give me another method to do ...

**Moodle 4.2.3
Postgres
Php 8.0.30**

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

This function will delete and recalculate the grades - **use with caution** though, it will also delete any manual overrides

```
grade_course_reset($courseid);
```

Or you could force the final grades to be regraded without deleting all the grades

```
grade_force_full_regrading($courseid);

grade_regrade_final_grades($courseid);
```

**Question 2**

For "course grade final note method or algorithm"

You can use formulas to calculate the grade

https://docs.moodle.org/403/en/Grade_calculations

1. Login as teacher or other user with permission to edit grades
2. Click on Grades in the course administration block
3. Click 'View > Grader Report'
4. Click 'Turn Editing On'; a 'Controls' bar should appear above the grades
5. Click the 'Calculator' icon above the grade item or category you wish to edit. Note: if you don't see this, then it must be enabled in Site administration>Grades>Report settings>Grader report>Show calculations
6. Start with an equal sign (=)
7. Type an expression using numbers, arithmetic operators, mathematical functions and ID numbers; for example =average()
8. Plug in your ID numbers (see below) enclosed in double square brackets, for example =[[item1]]+[[item2]]
9. Separate each function argument with a comma, as in =average([[item1]], [[item2]])+[[item3]])
10. Click the "Save Changes" button

Comment: Ok thank you so by your response you confirm that it's possible to create a local plugin to edit course grade ? if true how can i implement my algorithme if i want to use yours functions:
-grade_force_full_regrading($courseid);
-grade_regrade_final_grades($courseid);

it's event function i can implement it in lib.php ? if true, so i see a little how can i do it. else you can explain more please.

thank you.

Comment: Hello. So for recalculate all courses final grade with any algorithm, i suppose the grade must be changed directly into the database with $DB requetes after using yours funtions?

Comment: The 2 functions will reset the and recalculate the grade - for the algorithm though, go through the course admin above rather than use code

Comment: Ok thanks. But When or where should i call these fonctions ? is there an existing event function could i append in my lib.php to call these functions when any user finished an specific quiz ? Or when course grade must be recalculated.